# Cannot find item in database when one column is null

Tags: java, sql, database, join

I have a program which requires me to input the ID of a product and then will search a database in order to display details about that specific product.

The code works fine for every item in the database except productID 2 and productID 4 because they have no data stored in one of the columns (PRODUCT_TYPE).

I've got an if statement in my code which says:

```
else if (result.getString("PRODUCT_TYPE") == null && result.getString("DESCRIPTION ") == null)
{
System.out.println("Item ID: " + result.getString("STOCKITEM") + ". \nProduct name: " + result.getString("PRODUCT") + ". \nCost: £" + result.getString("COST") + ". \nStock level: " + result.getString("STOCKLEVEL") + ". \nProduct type: null.");
}
```

But I cannot figure out why it's unable to find the product if Product type is null but can still find it if description is null.

```
    try{        
        String searchCode = "SELECT PRODUCTS.PRODUCT, PRODUCTS.COST, PRODUCTS.DESCRIPTION, PRODUCT_STOCK.STOCKITEM , PRODUCT_STOCK.STOCKLEVEL FROM PRODUCT_TYPE INNER JOIN (PRODUCTS FULL OUTER JOIN PRODUCT_STOCK ON PRODUCTS.PRODUCTID = PRODUCT_STOCK.STOCKITEM) ON PRODUCT_TYPE.PRODTYPEID = PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_TYPE WHERE PRODUCTID = " + inputValue + ";";
        // sql statement searches the database for the required data

        Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(searchCode);
        boolean found = false;
        found = result.next();

        if (!found) { //if no data is found then display the error message and restart the product search method
            System.out.println("That product couldn't be found, please try again.");
            searchProduct();
        }
        else if (result.getString("PRODUCT_TYPE") == null && result.getString("DESCRIPTION ") == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Item ID: " + result.getString("STOCKITEM") + ". \nProduct name: " + result.getString("PRODUCT") + ". \nCost: £" + result.getString("COST") + ". \nStock level: " + result.getString("STOCKLEVEL") + ". \nProduct type: null.");
        }
        else if (result.getString("PRODUCT_TYPE") == null && result.getString("DESCRIPTION") != null){
            System.out.println("Item ID: " + result.getString("STOCKITEM") + ". \nProduct name: " + result.getString("PRODUCT") + ". \nCost: £" + result.getString("COST") + ". \nStock level: " + result.getString("STOCKLEVEL") + ". \nDescription: " + result.getString("DESCRIPTION") + ". \nProduct type: null.");
            }
        else if (result.getString("PRODUCT_TYPE") != null && result.getString("DESCRIPTION") == null){
                System.out.println("Item ID: " + result.getString("STOCKITEM") + ". \nProduct name: " + result.getString("PRODUCT") + ". \nCost: £" + result.getString("COST") + ". \nStock level: " + result.getString("STOCKLEVEL") +  ". \nDescription: null. \nProduct type: " + result.getString("PRODTYPE_DESC") + ".");
            }
        else if (result.getString("PRODUCT_TYPE") != null && result.getString("DESCRIPTION") != null){
            System.out.println("Item ID: " + result.getString("STOCKITEM") + ". \nProduct name: " + result.getString("PRODUCT") + ". \nCost: £" + result.getString("COST") + ". \nStock level: " + result.getString("STOCKLEVEL") + ". \nDescription: " + result.getString("DESCRIPTION") + ". \nProduct type: " + result.getString("PRODTYPE_DESC") + ".");
            }
        }
    catch (Exception e){ // if the product can't be found then display the error message and restart the product search method
        System.out.println("Could not find product.");
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        searchProduct();
    }

    //goes back to menu once the method has finished
    askUser();
}
```

Any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your SQL is doing a JOIN on PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_TYPE, which is null. This means the join won't join anything, because there is nothing to match with the null.

Comment: So is there any way to solve this? There isn't any thing else that could link to the other table that's the only column in the table regarding the other product type table.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a typo?

`result.getString("DESCRIPTION ") == null`

Should be

`result.getString("DESCRIPTION") == null`

Note the extra space in `"Description "` in your current version.

Comment: I've changed that and it is still saying "That product couldn't be found. I think it's something in the SQL query but I struggle with it so don't know what it is which is causing the program to be able to find products which have a value for PRODUCT_TYPE but can't find them for null values.